# How to get one span data into another span with the help of javascript?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Here the first span is receiving data from some other javascript source and what i want is that when this data comes it should be transferred to some the other span but i am not getting how to do this.

Here is my fiddle link http://

```js
// project | subproject | budget
data = [
["PrA", "SubPr1", 100],
["PrA", "SubPr2", 150],
["PrA", "SubPr3", 200],
["PrB", "SubPr4", 300],
["PrB", "SubPr5", 500],
["PrC", "SubPr6", 450]];

data = data.map(function (d) {
    return {
        project: d[0],
        subproject: d[1],
        budget: d[2]
    };
});

var ndx = crossfilter(data)
var projDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.project;});
var projGroup = projDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.budget;});


dc.rowChart("#projectChart")
    .renderLabel(true)
    .dimension(projDim)
    .group(projGroup)
    .xAxis().ticks(2);




dc.renderAll();
var c = 10;
var a = document.getElementById("abc").value;
if(a === NULL)
{
document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<div id="projectChart">
<div class="reset" >selected: <span class="filter" id = "abc"></span></div>
<div class="reset">
into:<span id = "xyz"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle.net/amru/mjput2fw/

Comment: `document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML/innerText`. `span` does not have `value` property..

Comment: `.value` is only for user input elements.

Comment: @RayonDabre Take `innerText` out of your vocabulary. It's nonstandard and doesn't exist in Firefox. The correct name is `textContent`.

Comment: @RayonDabre tell me how to implement this by implementing it in jsfiddle

Comment: @amru, I am not noob in D3 so can not help you with events but have corrected syntax mistakes/errors...Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/mjput2fw/1/